# Unexpected token N in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, cabeceras-http, fetch

Chicos Tengo un error que en mi NodeJS resto API, y no puede resolver esto. Mi idea es hacer un login github, esta aplicación funciona así:

- Redirección a github devolviendo un código temporal en callback.
- Enviar este código temporal a mi REST API y hacer una solicitud de búsqueda a otro endpoint de la API GitHub. Ésta petición debe devolver `access_token = 12345` (este token de acceso es un ejemplo), para enviar éste token al frontend, convertirlo en un token JWT y posteriormente almacenarlo en un localStorage para usarlo.

Mi código en NodeJS

```js
router.post("/users/github/:code",function(req,res){
    fetch('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/', {
        method: 'GET',
        client_id: 'xxxx',
        client_secret: 'xxxx',
        code: req.params.code,
        accept: 'json',
    })
   .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    });
 
});
```

PD: I use `node-fetch` module for this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu petición está mal, lo correcto es así:

```
fetch('https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      client_id: 'xxxx',
      client_secret: 'xxxx',
      code: req.params.code
    })
})
  .then(function(res) {
      return res.json();
  }).then(function(json) {
      console.log(json);
  });
});
```

Fíjate en la parte *headers* y *body*. En una petición *POST*, debes **enviar la data en el cuerpo (`body`)** de la petición. En caso envíes un JSON, debes **parsearlo a string** (por medio de `JSON.stringify`) y, además, debes especificar el `Content-Type` de la información que estás enviando, en tu caso  `application/json`.

> Por defecto la [API de GitHub devuelve texto plano como respuesta](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#2-github-redirects-back-to-your-site), pero puedes especificar qué tipo de dato quieres recibir por medio de la cabecera `Accept`:

```
headers: {
  Accept: 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
```